# Correct class design for a web project in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

We're in the process of rewriting our code in OOP and I'm trying to design a general framework for future projects (mostly to comply with DRY and keep the code slim and consistent).

For example I think it would be nice to have a base class `DatabaseObject`, which would source its properties from a database row. It would (among other things) use `__call()` and `property_exists()` to automate most getters. That way we'd don't have to potentially write all 100+ getters for every column in the database row (or update the class code with every change to the table).

Other classes like `Customer`, `Car` or `Article` would extend `DatabaseObject` (if they're sourced from a database) and inherit these methods, so we don't have to copy the database specific code into every class separately (which would just get more and more inconsistent over time).

Is this the correct...ish use of inheritance in a web project, or is this bad design? My colleague argues that this is somewhat a misuse of inheritance and that a customer sourced from a CSV file would need a separate class definition, which is a valid point.

With Interfaces we'd still have to copy the code into every class and traits (aside from requiring PHP 5.4) would not work for my `__call()` example above (I think).

So is there a better approach to my `DatabaseObject` concept?

**Edit:** Could someone explain the reason for the downvotes to me, so I can maybe delete and resubmit my question in a proper way?

Comment: [You may find that these set of standards will help you!](http://www.php-fig.org/)

Comment: Automating getters will result in lack of autocomplete. You at least will need to anotate them with `@method` in the child classes. Make some code generation tool that will create the entities with the anotations while extracting information from the DB. You may look at some of the modern ORMs which rely on this strategy.

Comment: @sjagr Thanks for the reply. We already conform to PSR actually. But it doesn't deal with specifics like this, as far as I know.

Comment: Why don't you use an ORM instead, such as Doctrine 2? And you can still use base data classes for your entities (DB objects), for common behaviours across all entities, and even for objects that do not correspond to a DB table

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way into mapping the database table into an object. Actually, people before you already invented the wheel. There are several ORMs in PHP that can do that work for you without any needs of reinventing the wheel - e.g. Doctrine, Propel...

However, the problems you might encounter in your current schema are that states of your objects. Your entities - `Car` or `Article` will have hard time keeping their state if all the logic around it is in an abstraction. You'd need a properties that are mapped to the table columns in order to keep the object changed, but the changes not commited. And only uppon e.g. `save()` method called, to commit changes.

Also, if you need an additional logic around this, let's say, you need to validate the name of the author of an article, you need that `setAuthor()` method physically written anywhere in order to change things on it.

The ORMs I have mentioned resolved these problems with a code generation tool, that examines the DB schema and creates classes with their physical getters and setters in the entity. Propel, for example, creates a class with the table name, with all the getters and setters in it and the logic there, but also creates a class that extends it in the public directory, so when you instantiate `Article` you instantiate the empty class that extends the `ArticleBase`. `ArticleBase` do have `setAuthor()` method that performs change upon the author e.g. UPDATE/INSERT. But when you need to perform additional logic in `setAuthor()` you just override it in `Article`, perform your logic and call `parent::setArticle()`.

This, also, resolves the problem with the autocompletion. The modern developers world made me rely too much on the auto complete. I cannot and will not remember the public API of each module I am using, nor the whole database lying under the application. So maybe I don't know if your `articles` table has `user_id` column for the author, or `author_id`. Thus, I will expect writing `$article->` to suggest me methods that I am able to use. Your scheme with `__call()` will result into lack of autocomplete suggestions, because no methods will be generation, nor any annotations.

Comment: Thanks, though I think you misunderstood my question (or I your answer, I guess). My question isn't about my `DatabaseObject` and its functionality, that was just one example. My question is a) if my use of inheritance is acceptable or misuse (I keep being told it's misuse and that customers aren't children of some database object etc.) and b) how I would go about loading customers from other sources like CSV or XML, when my customer class is specifically written to extend a database specific class (be it ORM or not). ORM is just a little over my head and not possible in the timeframe I have.

Comment: The inheritance is not misuse if all of your objects have something in common. You can introduce one more level of abstraction. All of your entities are children of `Entity` class, which, lets say, has one `save()` abstract method. Then you have two more abstract classes children of `Entity` -> `CsvObject` which implements `save()` and performs a save upon a .csv file. And `DatabaseObject` which implements `save()` and performs `update/insert`. If your entities has nothing in common, you can throw away the inheritance and just make standalone classes. Personally I would prefer the first one

Comment: Then switching from Database to Csv will just consist into changing `Customer extends DatabaseObject` to `Customer extends CsvObject`.

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm just dense here, but that wouldn't work within one project, right? Naming one CustomerCsv and CustomerDatabase would work, but that would defeat the point. To stay with my (albeit bad, as you explained) automatic getters example: I thought of `Customer extends AutoGetters implements DatabaseObject` and `Customer extends AutoGetters implements CsvObject`. But extending something like `AutoGetters` is really wrong and clearly not what you meant. I feel like I'm completely of the rails here. I really just don't want to copypaste basic functionality into every class that needs it.

Comment: In essence I need multiple inheritance, but I know that PHP doesn't have that. The usual answer on here is: rethink your class design. But I just don't know where I go wrong. I keep ending up  having to copypaste basic functionality and go completely against DRY.

Comment: @Steffen there are traits as of PHP 5.4. You may consider using traits for the basic functionality that would be copypasted otherwise. Also think about that code generation scripts I was talking from the beginning. Maybe you really need a script that creates files with classes, populate methods, etc

Comment: Thanks for the answers/time. Yeah, I don't think I'll go with my `DatabaseObject`/`__call()` idea anymore. I hadn't thought of autocomplete when I concocted that.